# Adjusting laptop display brightness doesn't work in Linux Mint 14

Tags: display, linux-mint, brightness, laptop-display

I recently installed Linux Mint 14 on my Samsung R580 laptop. The Fn-keys worked out of the box, I can switch screens, adjust volume and so on.

When I try to adjust the brightness (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>), the slider shows up and moves to the left and right, but screen brightness does not change at all, it always stays at 100%.

I tried to change the brightness in the system settings and it also doesn't do anything.

When I'm inactive for 5-10 minutes, the energy saving profile kicks in and the screen is dimmed. So the dimming *does* work, but not when I change it manually.

I found some threads stating that you should change the acpi_background setting to "vendor" in Grub config, but that didn't change anything for me.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Samsung R580, Ubuntu 10.04 and Brightness control](http://mcgivrer.fr/samsung-r580-ubuntu-1004-and-brightness-contr), not written for Mint
but may still work :

Edit the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file and add the RegistryDwords line (only that line) to the Device section:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Default Device"
  Driver "nvidia"
  Option "NoLogo" "True"
  Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Comment: thank you so much, my eyes love you ;-) accepted and bounty awarded. only the last line is relevant, the rest of my device section looked a bit different. and a restart was required. but now everything is more than fine

Answer (score 6):

Edit this line in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

Then:

```
update-grub
reboot
```

Comment: This is the only solution that solved my problem with my Dell 15R SE 7520 with Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

For linux mint version 8 +

- `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
- Find the line which says GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
- enter acpi_backlight=vendor between the quotes ("")
- `sudo update-grub`
- reboot your laptop / pc

Source:

- http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=45271

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Please try to add essential facts from the site to your answer. Otherwise, if the link goes down, your post will be totally useless.

Comment: thank you, but I already tried that. the FN keys are working, I see the slider moving when I'm using FN+up/down. But the screen brightness does not change at all