# Brightness slider disappeared after cinnamon upgrade

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia-geforce, brightness, cinnamon

Yesterday I decided to upgrade my system (Linux Mint 13). Cinnamon passed from 1.4 to 2.0.14.
However the slider to control the screen brightness disappeared.

I tried to follow this answer [Adjusting laptop display brightness doesn't work in Linux Mint 14](https://superuser.com/questions/527072/adjusting-laptop-display-brightness-doesnt-work-in-linux-mint-14) but I don't have `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

I also tried to edit `/etc/default/grub` as shown [here](http://www.mydellmini.com/forum/dell-inspiron-11z/25932-solution-screen-brightness-linux-mint.html) but didn't work.

Is there a solution?