# Unable to change brightness on Macbook Air using Linux Mint 18.1

Tags: linux, grub, linux-mint, xorg, brightness

Since installing Linux Mint (XFCE) on my late-2010 Macbook Air, I've had problems changing the brightness while using the proprietary Nvidia drivers.

The function keys for brightness have never worked (though curiously the volume keys do), but until recently I was able to adjust the brightness using the `xbacklight` command. However, I recently removed the `acpi_backlight=vendor` flag from my grub config, which removed even this ability. Putting the flag back in did not bring back my ability to use `xbacklight` for some reason, so now I have no way to adjust the brightness at all.

At this point I would be happy just to regain the ability to use `xbacklight`. Using the command now gives no output whatsoever, no errors, messages, nothing.

Relevant parts of my /etc/default/grub (`acpi_backlight=vendor` being the only thing I had removed when it stopped working):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet splash acpi_osi=linux 
acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I have a custom X11 config file at /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-brightness.conf:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Default Device"
  Driver "nvidia"
  BoardName "GeForce 320M"
  Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Does anyone know why removing the flag and putting it back in broke my ability to use `xbacklight`? (I've run `update-grub` several times to no avail).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjusting laptop display brightness doesn't work in Linux Mint 14](https://superuser.com/questions/527072/adjusting-laptop-display-brightness-doesnt-work-in-linux-mint-14)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not only limited to Macbook. Other brands even the Toshiba satellite L510 has the same problem. I have found a simple enough solution

In all Linux systems that I have encountered so far, even in android phones and other android based appliances, there are configuration files in the directory `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0` that pertain to screen brightness - to be more precise, the backlight of LED screens. Here is the output of `ls /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0`

Output of ls /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0:

[image]

Different systems have different screen brightness resolutions. My system has a resolution of 8 i.e. [0,7]. you can see the upper limit of your screen brightness resolution by `cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness`.

Then write whatever value you want to the file `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`, as long as the number is less than the `max_brightness` and your system will immediately attain that brightness value. For example, since my system has a resolution that ranges from 0-7, `echo 3 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` makes my screen half-way bright. while `echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` makes the backlight as dark as possible without shutting the screen.

for the sake of convenience use the following script to adjust your screen brightness from terminal. Drop the script file in `/bin` or some other directory in your shell's `$PATH` environmental variable with the name `backlight.sh` and make it executable. here is the script

`#!/bin/bash`

`## MAX_BRIGHTNESS variable takes the value in /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness`

`MAX_BRIGHTNESS=$(cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness);`

`error_report(){printf "error: the backlight brightness value \"$1\" is out of range, use only [0,$MAX_BRIGHTNESS]\n";}`

`if [ $1 -ge 0 ] &&  [ $1 -le $MAX_BRIGHTNESS ]; 
then echo $1 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness ; 
else error_report ; 
fi;`

after saving this script in a $PATH directory as `backlight.sh`, open a root terminal and run the following command.

`root@local.machine-A500# backlight.sh 0`

then your screen will go dark. play around with other values so long as the values don't exceed max_brightness.